# What is the difference between VERIFY and ATLVERIFY

Tags: c++, atl

What is the difference between the C++ macro VERIFY() and ATLVERIFY() ? And which one is better to use for COM objects?

Comment: I see documentation for [`VERIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcatwy09.aspx) but I [don't see an `ATLVERIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sks11ex0.aspx) macro

Comment: VERIFY is an MFC assertion (found in afx.h), ATLVERIFY is the ATL form (atldef.h)

Comment: Why don't you view the macro to see what the difference is?

Comment: F12 should do the trick in a recent VS version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some difference in how the errors are reported.  `ATLVERIFY` is defined as

```
#ifndef ATLVERIFY
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define ATLVERIFY(expr) ATLASSERT(expr)
#else
#define ATLVERIFY(expr) (expr)
#endif // DEBUG
#endif // ATLVERIFY
```

And `ATLASSERT` is

```
#ifndef ATLASSERT
#define ATLASSERT(expr) _ASSERTE(expr)
#endif // ATLASSERT
```

So it ends up in `_ASSERTE` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezb1wyez.aspx )

While `VERIFY` is

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define VERIFY(f)          ASSERT(f)
#else   // _DEBUG
#define VERIFY(f)          ((void)(f))
#endif // !_DEBUG
```

So it ends up in `ASSERT` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297139(v=vs.60).aspx )